# DeferredTreeContentManager and Eclipse resources

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to make a `TreeViewer` plugin for Eclipse with some objects that extend classes in `org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.*`. This worked fine with a normal tree, but since I need to load the resources on the fly I needed a lazy tree. I followed the tutorial [here](http://www.ceclipse.org/simple/?t1915.html) and it worked great. However if I make my `TreeObject` class extend something like `org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Folder` nothing in my tree will load.

An example would be too long to paste here so I put the source on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/rTQQ4br1). If I delete the "extends Folder" and comment out the `super()` call everything works. Otherwise nothing shows up in the tree.

Does anyone know why this is happening or how I can fix it?